# How Can i show the" same name" apperaing multiple times in a column as single name in row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the first table stored in database as shown and i have to apply the query on it to show it like the second table

[image]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Please, provide sample table data and the expected result as formatted text instead.

Comment: @jarlh click on this image and you will have a readable view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select subject, 
       max(case when exam = 'Mid1' then marks end) as Mid1,
       max(case when exam = 'Mid2' then marks end) as Mid2
from yourtable
group by subject
```

Comment: yeah it worked for me 
but is there any solution to this problem

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAhsan I'm not understanding your comment.  It worked for you, but is there any solution?  This is the solution...

Comment: sorry my bad I didn't write it correctly 
actually, I was asking for some other solution other than that you posted
and yes the solution u told worked for me :) just looking for some other solution too.